# Instalar e usar uma biblioteca via NPM

Tags: jquery, npm

Eu estou começando a entender o [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/) agora, sou muito old school e estou precisando me atualizar.

Instalei via NPM o Jquery e uma biblioteca qualquer para testar (Inputmask). Parece que deu tudo certo, as pastas foram criadas dentro da pasta node_modules e meu arquivo package.json ficou assim:

```
{
  "name": "npm_tutorial",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "testando a instalacao via npm",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "teste"
  ],
  "author": "caiocafardo",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "jquery": "^3.2.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "inputmask": "^3.3.5"
  }
}
```

Agora minha dúvida: como usar o Jquery e o Inputmask no HTML? Terei que chamar igual sempre fiz?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Ou tem algum jeito de chamar mais facilmente (tudo de uma vez)? Esse meu arquivo index.js ficou vazio, seria ele o cara que faz a mágica?

Comment: Estás a usar webpack, ou browserify? tens um servidor ou estás só a testar num ficheiro html estático?

Comment: Localmente, um ficheiro estático. Sobre webpack e browserify, desculpa, mas não estou usando nenhum dos dois....

Comment: Nesse caso funciona bem como está, partindo do principio que o ficheiro `.html` está na diretoria base do projeto. Conseguiste pôr a funcionar?

Comment: Sim, da forma tradicional usando script. Mas aí não tem vantagem algum em usar o NPM. Posso muito bem baixar o JS e chamar, certo? Queria entender qual a vantagem de usar o NPM.... pois se tiver que chamar igual sempre chamei, não vejo vantagem

Comment: Sim, exato. Usar o npm é só uma maneira prática de teres o ficheiro no teu projeto. Mas CDN é melhor se fores trabalhar online, senão (sendo offline) precisas mesmo do ficheiro localmente.

Comment: Mas via CDN usaria GitHub?

Comment: Não, usa diretamento do Google por exemplo: https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/#jquery